# Unzipping and zipping a working .xpi makes it stop working

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, zip, 7zip, xpi

I downloaded the basic Hello World xpi from Mozilla, and it installed in my Firefox without any problems. Then I unistalled the addon, unzipped the xpi, then, without changing anything inside it, zipped it again using 7zip. I tried to install it, and Firefox gave me a "This addon could not be installed because it appears to be corrupt" error.

Comment: You likely re-zipped it incorrectly, e.g. zipped the containing directory (`extracted/chrome.manifest` instead of just `chrome.manifest`). Without knowing the actually zip, there is no way to tell. Please provide a listing of what is contained in the zip (and/or the zip itself)

Comment: The contents are the same as in the xpi [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/5139/=xulschoolhello1.xpi). Anyway, I zipped the xulschoolhello1 directory, instead of its contents. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: @blacktrance. If you solved the problem, you should post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unzipping the .xpi produces a folder with the same name as the .xpi, with its contents. To create a working .xpi, zip the contents of that folder, not the folder itself.

Credit goes to [nmaier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/484441/nmaier).